# Master DNS server doesn't serve the clients

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver, ubuntu-14.04, dns-zone

Until yesterday I had a dedicated server with 2 IPs and Plesk. The NS, NS2 is running on same server, I'm using Plesk to add the domain records. Everything I worked great.

Yesterday I had to buy an other server, so I decided to use it as DNS server too, but without Plesk. I installed bind9 (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto#Secondary_Master_Server_configuration) and I added the following lines to named.local.conf:

```
zone "my-domain" {
     type slave;
     file "/var/cache/bind/db.my-domain.com";
     masters { MY_SERVER_IP; };
};
```

I didn't modify other settings. On the website above I saw an other modification in the conf file, but honestly I don't know what is it, and I didn't add it:

```
zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
     type slave;
     file "/var/cache/bind/db.192";
     masters { @ip_master; };
};
```

On the (A) server: In Plesk, Tools & Settings -> DNS Template Settings >> Transfer Restrictions Template, I added the IP of my (B) server to allowed list

After I restarted the bind everything looks fine ((B) syslog:

```
zone my-domain.com/IN: Transfer started.
transfer of 'my-domain.com/IN' from MY-SERVER-IP#53: connected using 192.96.206.50#49370
zone my-domain.com/IN: transferred serial 1425047310
transfer of 'my-domain.com/IN' from MY-SERVER-IP#53: Transfer completed: 1 messages, 14 records, 417 bytes, 0.094 secs (4436 bytes/sec)
zone my-domain.com/IN: sending notifies (serial 1425047310)
```

For my domains I updated the servers:

- ns.a-server.com (Server A - Plesk)
- ns2.a-server.com (Server A - Plesk)
- **ns3.b-server.com (Server B)**

The result of `@ns3.b-server.com my-domain.com` is looks fine.

I didn't finish the configuration of other applications on the server so I decided to turn it off for a night. In the morning I surprised when I tried to ping my-domain.com:

```
ping: cannot resolve my-domain.com: Unknown host
```

As far as I know the client tries to get the ip of the server from the master dns server, when it's unreachable it tries the slave server. In this situation I turned off the slave server. So where is the problem/misconfiguration?

Should I remove the ns2.a-server.com or it doesn't matter?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear where do you run the `ping`. But your assumption that

> client tries to get the ip of the server from the master dns server

is plain wrong. DNS client contacts the servers of /etc/resolv.conf and only these servers. The server makes a choice to respond in only one of these ways:

- if it is a `master` for the domain, it responds based on it's own zone files (it's own local disk and nothing else); the answer is authoritative and it ends the processing
- if it is a `slave` for the domain, it responds based on it's own zone files (it's own local disk and nothing else); the answer is authoritative and it ends the processing
- if it is neither, it passes the request to the `forwarders`; it ends the processing
- if not `master`, not `slave` and no `forwarders` configured, server tries to resolve the request on its own by asking the DNS all over the internet (recursive query - for a.b.c.com. it tries to resolve "." then "com." then "c.com." then "b.c.com." then "a.b.c.com." by querying various servers as specified by various NS records); the answer can be cached by server, it is non-authoritative, and it ends the processing

In your case, your `slave` could time-out its own zone file, and for some reason not be able to get a fresh one from `master`. Just one of possible causes.

Comment: I tried to ping on my own local pc. After I restarted the router I'm able to ping the server again. But I think it's not the perfect behaviour when the slave is not available.